# CSS: How to align text to baseline of height-adjusted input element?

Tags: html, css

According to the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) I should be able to set the text in an input element to the baseline if the element's display is set to `inline-block`.

I have a bunch of `input` elements whose height I have adjusted, but now when you try and type inside them the text is displayed vertically centered.

How do I get the text to appear at the bottom (baseline) of its input in CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/ay5y16ob/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text inputs aren't affected by the vertical align property, but you can fake it with top padding:

```
.i, i:focus {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
    outline: none;
    outline: 0;
    width: 90%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cw8esy2f/)**